# Convert List<int> to string of comma separated values

Tags: c#, list

having a `List<int>` of integers (for example: `1 - 3 - 4`)
how can I convert it in a string of this type?

For example, the output should be:

```
string values = "1,3,4";
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another solution would be the use of [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx). This is known to be **much slower** then the other provided solutions!

```
var ints = new List<int>{1,2,3,4};
var strings =
            ints.Select(i => i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                .Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + ", " + s2);
```

See comments below why you should not use it. Use `String.Join` or a `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: -1 Notoriously bad solution to create strings like this (especially when the list is long). String.Join or StringBuilder are the way to go. Sad for Stack Overflow that a low quality OP does not even know how to accept the best answer.

Comment: @GertArnold I agree with you. Just wanted to show another solution and forgot to mention anything performance. I tried to delete this answer but I can't. I will update the answer to not use it.

Comment: Perfect, could be fine this wau. Thank you

Answer (score 114):

```
var nums = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
var result = string.Join(", ", nums);
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in .NET 3.5 and earlier (the second parameter must be a string[]). See Albin Sunnanbo's answer.

Comment: The most suitable and clean solution.

Answer (score 20):

```
var ints = new List<int>{1,3,4};
var stringsArray = ints.Select(i=>i.ToString()).ToArray();
var values = string.Join(",", stringsArray);
```

Comment: Thank you Albin. E for the revers task, from a string of integer with commas, I need to obtain a List<int>.
Luigi

Comment: In .NET 4 [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) has an overload taking an `IEnumerable<T>` so this can be done without the intermediate array (this overload calls `ToString()` on each input element): `string.Join(",", ints)`.

Comment: @Ciupaz, for the reverse task, use [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string ToCommaString(this List<int> list)
{
    if (list.Count <= 0)
        return ("");
    if (list.Count == 1)
        return (list[0].ToString());
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(list[0].ToString());
    for (int x = 1; x < list.Count; x++)
        sb.Append("," + list[x].ToString());
    return (sb.ToString());
}

public static List<int> CommaStringToIntList(this string _s)
{
    string[] ss = _s.Split(',');
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    foreach (string s in ss)
        list.Add(Int32.Parse(s));
    return (list);
}
```

Usage:

```
String s = "1,2,3,4";
List<int> list = s.CommaStringToIntList();
list.Add(5);
s = list.ToCommaString();
s += ",6";
list = s.CommaStringToIntList();
```

Comment: Why did you post this alternate solution, when some very compact solutions using string.Join() had already been given?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegates for the same

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>( new int[] {20,22,1,5,1,55,3,10,30});
string intStringList = string.Join(",", intList.ConvertAll<string>(delegate (int i) { return i.ToString(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Stringify.Library nuget package

Example 1 (Default delimiter is implicitly taken as comma)

```
string values = "1,3,4";
var output = new StringConverter().ConvertFrom<List<int>>(values);
```

Example 2 (Specifying the delimiter explicitly)

```
string values = "1 ; 3; 4";
var output = new StringConverter().ConvertFrom<List<int>>(values), new ConverterOptions { Delimiter = ';' });
```